# MongoDB filter multi sub-documents

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I Have a document structured like this in mongo DB, and I want to filter to show only active subdocuments: active cars and active fruits.

```
    {
       "name":"Andre",
       "fruits":[
           {
              "active":true,
              "fruitname":"apple" 
           },{
              "active":false,
              "fruitname":"banana" 
           }
       ],
       "cars":[
           {
               "active":false,
               "carname":"ford"
           },{
               "active":true,
               "carname":"GM"
           },
       ]
    }
```

this is my desired result.

```
    {
       "name":"Andre",
       "fruits":[
           {
              "active":true,
              "fruitname":"apple" 
           }
       ],
       "cars":[
          {
               "active":true,
               "carname":"GM"
           },
       ]
    }
```

I've tried `Aggregate` but when any cars or any fruits active, it's return nothing.

```
    m_object.aggregate([
        { $match : {
           "name": "andre"
       }},
       { $unwind : "$fruits" },
       { $unwind : "$cars" },
       { $match : {
        'fruits.active':{$eq: true}
        }},
       { $match : {
        'cars.active':{$eq: true}
        }},

    { $group : {
       "name": "$name",
       cars: { $addToSet : "$cars" }
       fruits: { $addToSet : "$fruits" }
    }}
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('result');
    });
```

Is there any way to omit the `"active":false` subdocuments in those subdocuments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline to get the desired result:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "name": "Andre",
            "fruits.active": true,
            "cars.active": true
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$fruits" },
    { "$unwind": "$cars" },
    {
        "$match": {            
            "fruits.active": true,
            "cars.active": true
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "name": "$name"
            },
            "cars": { "$addToSet" : "$cars" },
            "fruits": { "$addToSet" : "$fruits" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "cars": 1,
            "fruits": 1
        }
    }    
]

m_object.aggregate(pipeline)
        .exec(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('result');
        });
```

Or you can use the **[aggregation pipeline](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** builder as follows:

```
m_object.aggregate()
        .match({
            "name": "Andre",
            "fruits.active": true,
            "cars.active": true
         })
        .unwind("fruits")
        .unwind("cars")
        .match({
            "fruits.active": true,
            "cars.active": true
         })
        .group({
            "_id": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "name": "$name"
            },
            "cars": { "$addToSet" : "$cars" },
            "fruits": { "$addToSet" : "$fruits" }
        })
        .project({
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "cars": 1,
            "fruits": 1
        })
        .exec(callback);
```

Comment: It worked, BUT if all cars are `active: false` nothing at all `[ ]` is returned. is there any way to use this solution and if all cars are disabled get `[{"name":andre", fruits[{..},{..}], "cars":[]}]` instead of `[]`

Comment: @AndreTorbitoni It really is not a good idea to change your question the way you have. It is very misleading to people who come along and see that answers provided do not match what you have asked. If you post another question I will be as will others happy to answer it. The general case here is one question one answer. I can answer your additional question but It should be another question entirely. Please post it separately.

Comment: Sorry, I've write another question for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199798/mongodb-aggregation-retuns-empty