# mongoDB Aggregation retuns empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

extending this following question: [MongoDB filter multi sub-documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198116/mongodb-filter-multi-sub-documents) which I want to filter a document to show only active subdocuments: active cars and active fruits.

Using the aggregation pipeline build by [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam) in the following document, where all `fruits` are disabled

```
{
   "name":"Andre",
   "fruits":[
       {
          "active":false,
          "fruitname":"apple" 
       },{
          "active":false,
          "fruitname":"banana" 
       }
   ],
   "cars":[
       {
           "active":false,
           "carname":"ford"
       },{
           "active":true,
           "carname":"GM"
       },
   ]
}
```

aggregation pipeline used:

```
var pipeline = [
{
    "$match": {
        "name": "Andre",
        "fruits.active": true,
        "cars.active": true
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$fruits" },
{ "$unwind": "$cars" },
{
    "$match": {            
        "fruits.active": true,
        "cars.active": true
    }
},
{ 
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": "$name"
        },
        "cars": { "$addToSet" : "$cars" },
        "fruits": { "$addToSet" : "$fruits" }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": "$_id.name",
        "cars": 1,
        "fruits": 1
    }
}    
]

m_object.aggregate(pipeline)
        .exec(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('result');
        });
```

instead of getting

```
[{
   "name":"Andre",
   "fruits":[],
   "cars":[
      {
           "active":true,
           "carname":"GM"
       },
   ]
}]
```

aggregation returns

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following aggregation pipeline, it doesn't return an empty array for the inactive elements but is closer to the result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "name": "Andre",
            "$or": [
                { "fruits.active": true },
                { "cars.active": true }
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$fruits" },
    { "$unwind": "$cars" },
    {
        "$match": {            
            "$or": [
                { "fruits.active": true },
                { "cars.active": true }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "active_cars": "$cars.active",
            "active_fruits": "$fruits.active",
            "cars": 1,
            "fruits": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "cars": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$active_cars", true] },
                    "$cars",
                    {}
                ]
            },
            "fruits": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$active_fruits", true] },
                    "$fruits",
                    {}
                ]
            }
        }
    },   
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "name": "$name"
            },
            "cars": { "$addToSet" : "$cars" },
            "fruits": { "$addToSet" : "$fruits" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "cars": 1,
            "fruits": 1
        }
    }    
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "cars" : [ 
                {
                    "active" : true,
                    "carname" : "GM"
                }
            ],
            "fruits" : [{}],
            "name" : "Andre"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the very first operation, the query criteria, in the pipeline:

```
"$match": {
   "name": "Andre",
   "fruits.active": true,
   "cars.active": true
}
```

In English: "find me all documents with `name = Andre` where there is at least one active fruit **and** at least one active car."

So you're *explicitly* requesting *not* to get any results where there are no active fruits and cars, hence the result is empty.